# Problem with liking/tagging and react to Instagram-photo of 1 special person

Tags: instagram

My wife (A) and her daughter (B) both have a (private) Instagram-account and they have problems with liking/tagging of and reacting to each others photos:

A can follow B and see B's photos. But A cannot like B's photos, after clicking the like-symbol it turns reds but immediately turns back to grey. A can tag B to a photo but after that it immediately disappears. A can type a reaction to B's photos but after that we get an error message. But yes, A can see B's photos, no problem.

Other way around: B cannot find and follow A's account. When B searches for A, she get no result. Then we tried B clicking on A's account in a reaction of someone else (C) photo. Then B can see A's account but after clicking the follow-button it becomes green and immediately returns back to grey.

Strange enough A and B both can follow other people and like/tag/react to their photos.

Weird. What is the problem? Can an account be corrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like one person is `blocking` the other person. Whenever you do something on instagram, the immediate feedback like the heart popping up is to show you that you've liked something, but if the "Liked" turns back to "Like" that means Instagram never actually added that like from your account to the photo.

Because the accounts are private, they both have to accept each other's follow requests before being able to do anything.

One other thing could be that one account is blocking the other. You can check this by having User A go to User B's profile and click on the top right menu button (Share icon), and see if it shows as "Unblock" or "Block" user.

Comment: Excellent. A was blocking B (no idea why, I think accidentally). Now I works. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad you got that figured out! :D